# Findstr too slow on UNC batch script

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, findstr, unc

I am running a script that goes through network folders and saves the found files, however it is taking too long to run. I have tried isolating the findstr to a single folder and it runs at an okay time, so I assume it has something to do with the FOR loop.

```
@echo off

setlocal

set SERVERS=server1 server2 server3 server4

cls
echo Type below the query parameters:
set /p year=Year (4 digits): 
set /p month=Month (2 digits): 
set /p day=Day (2 digits): 
set /p query=Query string: 
cls
echo Results:
del /F /Q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\found_files\*" 2>nul
if not exist "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\found_files" mkdir "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\found_files"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('for %%i in ^(%SERVERS%^) do @findstr /S /I /M /C:"%query%" "\\%%i\folder_structure\*%year%-%month%-%day%*.xml"') do copy /Y "%%a" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\found_files" >nul & echo %%a & set found=1
echo.
if "%found%"=="1" (
    echo File^(s^) saved successfully!
) else (
    echo No files found!
)
echo.
pause
if "%found%"=="1" explorer C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\found_files
```

Comment: Nesting `for` loops will slow your code down, but not necessarily to the extent that you're experiencing. I suspect that the bottleneck is from accessing the file on the UNC path, and that temporarily mounting that path as a network drive will speed things up, but I have no way of testing that.

Comment: keep in mind redirections and use of echo to output results on an each iteration basis will drastically slow things down.

Comment: @T3RR0R - Redirecting to nul on each iteration should not have much impact, as it never takes time to open a file. I tested 10000 `>nul` redirects in a tight loop, and it took only 1.6 seconds, whereas redirecting only once outside the loop took 1.2 seconds. That is a difference, but likely inconsequential. Iterative redirection becomes unacceptably slow when using something like `>>"file"` because it must reopen and reposition the file to the end for each iteration.

Comment: @SomethingDark - I always considered mapping a network drive to a UNC path to be nothing more than a convenience, or else a way to use the path with a command that does not understand UNC paths. I doubt it will save any processing time. But I guess we won't know until it is tried. The simplest way to map a UNC path is with `PUSHD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is already optimized pretty well. I don't think there is much you can do to speed things up.

I suspect your problem is that `FINDSTR` is running on your local machine, and it must scan the files on all UNC paths (almost surely not local). This means the entire content of every file must be transmitted across your network. If your system is anything like where I work, that could be a nightmare. Our network drive performance is pathetic (more than a factor of 100 slower than local drive)!

Squashman (and SomethingDark) were somewhat concerned about your outer `FOR /F` executing a nested `FOR` statement. But I believe that is the most efficient way. When `FOR /F` iterates command output, it must launch a new process to execute the command. Your current script only needs one sub-process.

The more "traditional" approach would be to move the `%SERVERS%` iteration outside the inner loop as follows:

```
for %%i in (%SERVERS%) do for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (
  'findstr /S /I /M /C:"%query%" "\\%%i\folder_structure\*%year%-%month%-%day%*.xml"'
) do copy /Y "%%a" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\found_files" >nul & echo %%a & set found=1
```

But this is actually less efficient because it must launch a new sub-process for each UNC path within `%SERVERS%`. That being said, I don't think the difference is significant compared to the actual bottle neck of transmitting the file content across the network.

To show the impact of one vs. 100 sub-processes, I ran a quick comparison of the following logically equivalent (but meaningless) commands:

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'for /l %%N in ^(1 1 100^) do @findstr /m "^" *'
) do echo %%F>nul
:: This took 39 seconds on my machine

for /l %%N in (1 1 100) do for /f %%F in (
  'findstr /m "^" *'
) do echo %%F>nul
:: This took 60.9 seconds on my machine
```

Comment: Your example does makes sense but I am also wondering if using `FINDSTR /S` is slower then using a `FOR /R` to first iterate the files and then use that with `find` or `findstr`

Comment: @Squashman - If anything I would think it would be faster to let `FINDSTR` navigate the tree given that there is overhead in launching an external command. Though `FINDSTR /S` perhaps should be avoided because there is a bug that can cause it to miss files if short file names are enabled on the drive.

Comment: I agree with you, must be a network limitation and amount of files. I believe I will have to look for other ways to search for them, if you have any suggestions I'll gladly accept them, thank you for you thorough explanation :)

Comment: @GabrielVicente - Not just the number of files, but also the size of each file. I believe `FINDSTR /M` is smart enough to short circuit as soon as it finds a match. But if there is no match, then it must search the entire file. I forgot to mention there is also the time it takes to copy the matched files across the network.

Answer (score -2):

```
@echo off

set SERVERS=server1,server2,server3,server4

cls
echo Type below the query parameters:

:: Type echo %date% on command prompt if its returns the current date dd/mm/yyyy format, you can load the variables using a substring:

set year=%date:~6,4%
set month=%date:~3,2%
set day=%date:~0,2%

set /p query=Query string: 

:: set counter for files founded
set found=0

cls
echo Results:

if not exist "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\found_files" (mkdir "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\found_files") else (del /F /Q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\found_files\*" 2>nul)

for /f %%i in (%SERVERS%) do ('@find /i /c "%query%" "\\%%i\folder_structure\*%year%-%month%-%day%*.xml"') do (
    
    if "%%i"=="1" (set /a found=%found%+1 && copy /Y "\\%%i\folder_structure\*%year%-%month%-%day%*.xml" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\found_files" >nul && echo File^(s^) saved successfully! & echo.) else (echo No files found!)

)
echo.
pause
if %found% gtr 0 (explorer C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\found_files)
```

Comment: Please do not write non-English posts. SO is an English-only site.

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to make this work, even by rearranging the code it errors out with "do was not expected at this time" or "server1 was not expected at this time".

Comment: @T3RR0R I don't want to sound rude but I would catch if the strings required escaping, I believe the FOR loop provided by Heitor is kind of wrong :) Don't worry, plenty of people helping, we will get to it soon enough.